# JavaScript confirm box...revert change on cancel

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a drop down box as shown : 
[image]

When I change the subject, the alert box shown below appears:

[image]

Code :

```
$("#createquiz_subject").bind("change", (function() { 
    if(quiz.length !== 0){ 
    var r = confirm("The questions selected will be cleared"); 
    if (r === true) { 
        $("#leftValues").empty(); 
    } else { 

    } 
 } 
}));
```

If I click on OK, then the topic and lesson changes. The same happens when I click on cancel.
When the user clicks on cancel, I want the subject to remain the same which was present before changing it.
How do I carry out this functionality.

Comment: @cr0ss What do you mean?

Comment: please share jsfiddle. and you don't need extra brackets before start function()

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar How do I share jsfiddle

Comment: visit this http://jsfiddle.net/  just add your code in respective areas, select jquery library from left and update. It will change the url in browser. copy that url and share it with us.

Answer (score 0):

You can work around this by first remembering the currently selected section and then manually reverting to it.

```
var subject = $('#creatquiz_subject');
var currentSubj = subject.val();
subject.bind("change", (function() { 
    if (!quiz.length) { return; } // Better to just short-circuit here?
    if (confirm("The questions selected will be cleared")) { 
        $("#leftValues").empty();
        currentSubj = subject.val(); // Update the current subject var
    } else { 
        subject.val(currentSubj);  // Reset to current subject
    } 
}));
```

Comment: I checked the output of var currentSubj = subject.val(); using console.log
It shows undefined.

Answer (score -1):

Only one way . Pseudocode is :

```
<script>
   var lastvalue = null;
</script>

<select .... onmousedown="lastvalue = this.index">

....
</select>

oncancel 
  select.index = lastvalue
```

tweak the code as per your implementation and jquery used(if used)

Comment: whts the problem. why it is down voted. I have tried and tested it.

Comment: First of all, it's obtrusive JavaScript. You don't write code like that nowadays. Secondly, this is a jQuery question.